# How to get the number of rows from a JDBC ResultSet?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get the row count from ResultSet/ResultSetMetaData but its not giving row count methods. Can anyone help to find the row count of resultSet?

I took all the value from database table Using selenium.

Comment: is it not returned as a List?

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Its not giving as list. Giving as ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery(query);

Comment: Thanks for the revenge downvote. This kind of behavior really makes being on this site and helping such outstanding individuals as yourself worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resultSet.last();
int size = resultSet.getRow();
resultSet.beforeFirst();
System.out.println("row size is" + size);
```

But will be better to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`

Comment: Its working ! Thanks.